# Is it simple present tense or imperative mood?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, present-simple, imperative-sentences

*Evernote is an easy-to-use, free app that helps you remember everything across all of the devices you use. Stay organized, save your ideas and improve productivity. Evernote lets you take notes, capture photos, create to-do lists, record voice reminders--and makes these notes completely searchable, whether you are at home, at work, or on the go.*

*Key Features:*

- *Sync all of your notes across the computers and devices you use*
- *Create and edit text notes, to-dos and task lists*
- *Save, sync and share files*
- *Search for text inside images*
- *Organize notes by notebooks and tags*
- *Email notes and save tweets to your Evernote account*
- *Connect Evernote to other apps and products you use*
- *Share notes with friends and colleagues via Facebook and Twitter*

My question is, should I understand these key features in simple present tense? Like this:

> Key Features:
>
> - Evernote syncs all of your notes across the computers and devices you use
> - Evernote creates and edits text notes, to-dos and task lists
> - Evernote saves, syncs and shares files
> - Evernote searches for text inside images
> - Evernote organizes notes by notebooks and tags
> - Evernote emails notes and saves tweets to your Evernote account
> - Evernote connects Evernote to other apps and products you use
> - Evernote shares notes with friends and colleagues via Facebook and Twitter

Or imperative mood? Like this:

> Key Features:
>
> - Sync all of your notes across the computers and devices you use ( you do it)
> - Create and edit text notes, to-dos and task lists (you do it)
> - Save, sync and share files (you do it)
> - Search for text inside images (you do it)
> - Organize notes by notebooks and tags (you do it)
> - Email notes and save tweets to your Evernote account(you do it)
> - Connect Evernote to other apps and products you use(you do it)
> - Share notes with friends and colleagues via Facebook and Twitter (you do it )

And my second question is:

> sync all of your notes ***across*** the computers and devices you use.

What does *across* mean in this sentence? Does it means **between** the computers and devices you use? I couldn't understand.

I hope I could explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The sentences use present simple. You already presented the full meaning.
2. They are definitely not imperatives.
3. - across devices = on all devices on which Evernote is supported, even if they are not of the same type (e.g. computer vs. smartphone, Windows vs. Linux)
   - sync across devices = transfer the data between all devices, so all of the devices will show the same information

Comment: thank you so much that's so important for me. I have just one more question what's the meaning of "on the go" in this sentence: " capture your ideas and inspirations on the go"? Thank you so much again

Comment: "on the go" = whenever it happens. You do not plan to sit and think about ideas, but you write down the ideas whenever they come to your mind.

Comment: It is a variant of the headline abbreviation as used in advertisements, which is best read as abbreviating "The key features let you do this, and this and this."  Read each line as "You can X" or more fussily "There is a feature which allows you  to X".